# Graceful shutdown of threads and executor

Tags: java, multithreading

The following piece of code tries to accompolish this.

The code loops forever and checks if there are any pending requests to be processed. If there is any, it creates a new thread to process the request and submits it to the executor. Once all the threads are done,it sleeps for 60 seconds and again checks for pending requests.

```
public static void main(String a[]){
    //variables init code omitted
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
    ExecutorCompletionService<Long> comp = new ExecutorCompletionService<Long>(service);
    while(true){
        List<AppRequest> pending = service.findPendingRequests();
        int noPending = pending.size();
        if (noPending > 0) {
            for (AppRequest req : pending) {
                Callable<Long> worker = new RequestThread(something, req);
                comp.submit(worker);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < noPending; i++) {
            try {
                Future<Long> f = comp.take();
                long name;
                try {
                    name = f.get();
                    LOGGER.debug(name + " got completed");
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    LOGGER.error(e.toString());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.toString());
            }
        }
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60);
    }

  }
```

My question is most of the processing done by these threads deal with database. And this program will run on a windows machine. What happens to these threads when someone tries to shutdown or logoff the machine.? How to gracefully shutdown the running threads and also the executor.?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

A typical orderly shutdown of an ExecutorService might look something like this:

```
final ExecutorService executor;

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        executor.shutdown();
        if (!executor.awaitTermination(SHUTDOWN_TIME)) { //optional *
            Logger.log("Executor did not terminate in the specified time."); //optional *
            List<Runnable> droppedTasks = executor.shutdownNow(); //optional **
            Logger.log("Executor was abruptly shut down. " + droppedTasks.size() + " tasks will not be executed."); //optional **
        }
    }
});
```

*You can log that the executor still had tasks to process after waiting the time you were willing to wait.
**You can attempt to force the executor's worker Threads to abandon their current tasks and ensure they don't start any of the remaining ones.

Note that the solution above will work when a user issues an interrupt to your `java` process or when your `ExecutorService` only contains daemon threads. If, instead, the `ExecutorService` contains non-daemon threads that haven't completed, the JVM won't try to shutdown, and therefore the shutdown hooks won't be invoked.

If attempting to shutdown a process as part of a discrete application lifecycle (not a service) then shutdown code should not be placed inside a shutdown hook but at the appropriate location where the program is designed to terminate.

Comment: This is backwards. Assuming the `ExecutorService` is one of the typical values returned by `Executors` factory methods, the backing threads are non-daemon threads. The shutdown hook won't be invoked until those threads exit, and that won't happen until the `ExecutorService` is shutdown. Your solution will only if the threads of the executor are non-daemon or if your program receives a user interrupt.

Comment: The OP is asking specifically about the case in which the JVM has been asked to perform an orderly shutdown. Regardless, the content of the answer is accurate, one need only not do this in a shutdown hook to terminate the executor service earlier.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly. I guess I missed that part of their question. Can you add a third `***` to clarify that bit?

Comment: Please feel free to edit. You have a valid point about planning termination of a program, as opposed to a service.

Comment: I prefer sout,because log4j could be unloaded at that time

Answer (score 9):

The book "[Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)" states:

> 7.4. JVM Shutdown
>
> The JVM can shut down in either an
>   orderly or abrupt manner. An orderly
>   shutdown is initiated when the last
>   "normal" (nondaemon) thread
>   terminates, someone calls System.exit,
>   or by other platform-specific means
>   (such as sending a SIGINT or hitting
>   Ctrl-C). [...]
>
> 7.4.1. Shutdown Hooks
>
> In an orderly shutdown, the JVM first
>   starts all registered shutdown hooks.
>   Shutdown hooks are unstarted threads
>   that are registered with
>   Runtime.addShutdownHook. The JVM makes
>   no guarantees on the order in which
>   shutdown hooks are started. If any
>   application threads (daemon or
>   nondaemon) are still running at
>   shutdown time, they continue to run
>   concurrently with the shutdown
>   process. When all shutdown hooks have
>   completed, the JVM may choose to run
>   finalizers if runFinalizersOnExit is
>   true, and then halts. The JVM makes no
>   attempt to stop or interrupt any
>   application threads that are still
>   running at shutdown time; they are
>   abruptly terminated when the JVM
>   eventually halts. If the shutdown
>   hooks or finalizers don't complete,
>   then the orderly shutdown process
>   "hangs" and the JVM must be shut down
>   abruptly. [...]

The important bits are, 
*"The JVM makes no attempt to stop or interrupt any application threads that are still running at shutdown time; they are abruptly terminated when the JVM eventually halts."* so I suppose the connection to the DB will abruptly terminate, if no shutdown hooks are there to do a graceful clean up (if you are using frameworks, they usually do provide such shutdown hooks). In my experience, session to the DB can remain until it is timed out by the DB, etc. when the app. is terminated without such hooks.

Answer (score 5):

Since adding a shutdown hook to explicitly call `shutdown()` didn't work for me, I found an easy solution in Google's Guava:
[com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.getExitingExecutorService](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#getExitingExecutorService%28java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor%29).

Comment: Still, it's a bit problematic since `MoreExecutors.getExitingExecutorService` accepts only `ThreadPoolExecutor` instances. As a result, you have to manually define those executors instead of simply calling, for instance, `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` which returns `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 3):

You can either call `shutdown()` on the `ExecutorService`:

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which
>   previously submitted tasks are
>   executed, but no new tasks will be
>   accepted.

or you can call `shutdownNow()`:

> Attempts to stop all actively
>   executing tasks, halts the processing
>   of waiting tasks, and returns a list
>   of the tasks that were awaiting
>   execution.
>
> There are no guarantees beyond
>   best-effort attempts to stop
>   processing actively executing tasks.
>   For example, typical implementations
>   will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so
>   any task that fails to respond to
>   interrupts may never terminate.

Which one you call depends how badly you want it to stop....

Comment: I am facing following issue in my web app.How to stop memory leaks .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39166512/memory-leak-error-in-tomcat-server-even-after-removed-quartz-related-code

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, i use to get error like

o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase :: The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [pool-2-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)

Bellow code fixed it

```
private ThreadPoolExecutor executorPool;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    log.debug("Initializing ThreadPoolExecutor");
    executorPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 3, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1));
}

@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
    log.debug("Shuting down ThreadPoolExecutor");
    executorPool.shutdown();
}
```